# How to send a list of objects to controller via Ajax using asp net core 3.1?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to send a list of objects to controller using ajax and asp .net core. My issue is very very simple and there are lots of answers in SO about my issue but none of them solved my issue. I am new at ASP.NET CORE but very experienced at ASP.NET( the normal one).

When debbuging I get a `null` list of object.

This is my code:

```
var detalleVenta = new Array();
    detalleVenta.length = 0;


     $.each($("#tableventa tbody tr"), function () {
                detalleVenta.push({
                    ProductoId: $(this).find('td:eq(6)').html(),
                });
            });

console.log(detalleVenta);

  var datos =
{  
    // ignore this, i am trying to capture other data.
    "Nit": document.getElementById('Nit').value,
    "Nombres":document.getElementById('nombres').value,
    "NoComprobante":document.getElementById('nocomprobante').value,
    "ClienteId":document.getElementById('clienteselect').value,
    "Direccion":document.getElementById('direccion').value,
    "FormaPago":document.getElementById('selectformapago').value,
    

    // This is the list I want to send to controller
    "detalle": detalleVenta,
};

  $.ajax(
    {     
        url: '/Venta/GuardarVenta/',        
        method:"POST",
        data: datos,
        traditional: true,      
        success: function(data, state) { 
            location.reload();
            return;
        }, 
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, txt) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            return;
        }

    });
```

In the `console.log(detalleVenta);` code I get this:

[image]

but when hitting parameters controller, I get this:

[image]

Here are my C# code:

```
public class VentaController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult GuardarVenta(List<Binderr> detalle, Venta venta)
   {
   }
}
public class Binderr
{
    public string ProductoId {get;set;}
}
```

The parameter `Venta venta` captures good the parameters but the list `detalle` does not. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: tried `public JsonResult GuardarVenta(Binderr[] detalle, Venta venta` got same results, list is null in the controller.

[image]

Comment: You're sending an array and accepting a list?

Comment: tried `public JsonResult GuardarVenta(Binderr[] detalle, Venta venta)` and did not work. Same results.

Comment: I deleted my answer because it's not right, but this is likely a matter of figuring out the right data type to accept in your method. Your POST payload shows that AJAX is sending an array of Binderr objects called detalle, but you've tried receiving that in your method and it didn't work.  I'm stumped!

Comment: do you think this is asp net core issue? because in asp.net this worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the easiest way is to pass the array to the backend in the form of `Json`.

Here is a simple example:

```
 var detalleVenta =
            [
            { id: "1" },
            { id: "2" },
            { id: "3" }
            ]
       
        $.ajax({
            "type": "POST",
            "url": '/Venta/GuardarVenta/',
            "dataType": "json",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "data": JSON.stringify(detalleVenta),
            })
```

Controller(`Add [FromBody]`):

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GuardarVenta([FromBody]List<Binderr> detalle)
{
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I do not know why my issue looked sooo easy and you solved it in seconds. I noticed my mistake was for not adding quotation marks inside ajax code. For example dataType instead of "dataType", wow does the quotation marks matter? and I have never heard of such `[FromBody]`. Thank you.

Comment: Quotation marks are not required, you can write it or not, you can try it.

Comment: Your answer helped me but I am still having some issues and I am struggling. Can you help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088046/asp-net-core-mvc-ajax-not-working-properly

Comment: I am stil stuck I do not know how to pass more data appart from that mentioned.