# ASP.NET Core MVC Ajax not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

My issue is very very simple but I have not found any solution about this issue in the entire internet. I am new at ASP.NET CORE MVC and I feel its AJAXs is very hard to understand compared to the normal ASP.NET.

Well I am trying to pass an array/list of objects to controller but I cant make this. It is Very simple but it does not work the way I want ( In the normal ASP.NET MVC worked great).

For example I have this:

```
var detalleVenta = new Array();

     $.each($("#tableventa tbody tr"), function () {

                 detalleVenta.push( 
                     {
                         "ProductoId" :  $(this).find("td").eq(6).html(),
                         "Cantidad" :  $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(),
                         "Precio" :  $(this).find("td").eq(3).html(),
                         "Total" :  $(this).find("td").eq(4).html() 
                     }
                     ); 
            });

        $.ajax({
          method:"POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(detalleVenta),
          "dataType": "json",
          "contentType": "application/json",
           url: '@Url.Action("GuardarVenta", "Venta")',
           traditional: true,         
           success: function(data, textStatus) { 
           if (data == "OK" ){
           location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Compra")'          
        }
    }
        ,
        })
```

MVC controller:

```
public JsonResult GuardarVenta([FromBody]List<DetalleBinding> detalle)
{
      ...
}

public class DetalleBinding
{
    public string ProductoId {get; set;}
    public string Cantidad {get;set;}
    public string Precio {get;set;}
    public string Total {get;set;}
}
```

This way worked for me, ajax sends the list successfully data to controller:

[image]

But my issue is... what if I want to send more data appart from that data? I Normally write it in JSON format like this : `data : { "detalle" : detalleVenta, "Name" : "Mary", "Age" : 34}` but my issue is that this does not work for me.

I tried this:

```
 $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    data: {"detalle" : JSON.stringify(detalleVenta)},
    "dataType": "json",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    url: '@Url.Action("GuardarVenta", "Venta")',
    traditional: true,         
    success: function(data, textStatus) { 
    if (data == "OK" ){
        location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Compra")'          
        }
    }
        ,
        })
```

But it does not bind to controller and gives me null.

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

This is what `console.log(JSON.stringify(detalleVenta))` shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0#sources) you can see:

`Don't apply [FromBody] to more than one parameter per action method. Once the request stream is read by an input formatter, it's no longer available to be read again for binding other [FromBody] parameters.`

So if you want to send more data ,the easiest way is through querystring,like below(change url):

```
$.ajax({
      method:"POST",
      data: JSON.stringify(detalleVenta),
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json",
      url: "Venta/GuardarVenta?age=34&name=Marry",
      traditional: true,         
      success: function(data, textStatus) { 
      if (data == "OK" ){
      location.href = '@Url.Action("Index","Compra")'          
    }
```

Action:

```
public JsonResult GuardarVenta([FromBody]List<DetalleBinding> detalle,int age,string name)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: What if I want to send 2 lists to parameter?  Will it work inside `Venta/GuardarVenta/? <LIST HERE>`, Well I am actually trying to send 2 lists and normal data to controller.

Comment: You can create a ViewMdel to wrap two classes in one class, and then accept the ViewModel.

Comment: Oh, does ajax accept viewModel? Never tried that but... Do I have to name the same json name to my property? for example in ViewModel `public List<class>  mylist;` and in ajax like this `data : {"mylist" : list, .. and so on}`, and in method `public JsonResult Save (ViewModel hi)`, right?

Comment: Not like that,you need to add it to your array,and then send it just like `data: JSON.stringify(detalleVenta)`

Comment: Oh but how could I send to array inside `data: `, I tried like this `data : JSON.stringify(detalleVenta1, detalleVenta2)`